# How I can create my own password in an empty membership table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I need to create a user in an empty [aspnet_Membership] table.

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
{       
    byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
    byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
    byte[] bRet = null;
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
    System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm s = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create(Membership.HashAlgorithmType);
    bRet = s.ComputeHash(bAll);          
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
}
```

I am using ASP.NET authentication to login but it couldn't login to web site because of wrong password.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="SQLConnectionString"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="3" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         applicationName="eShop"           
         passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

---

```
    password = EncodePassword(password, "asas" + password);    
    string userId = "0";
    SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand();
    c.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select UserId From aspnet_Users Where UserName ='" + username + "'";
    userId = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
    cmd.CommandText = string.Empty;
    c.CommandText = "insert InTo aspnet_Membership ([ApplicationId], [UserId], [Password], [PasswordSalt], [PasswordFormat]) ";
    c.CommandText += "Values (2 , " + userId + ",'" + password + "','" + password + "', 1)";
    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and I have a simple asp.net login control How I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to change the database directly. If you want to add a new user programmatically, use the [Membership.CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es.aspx) method. The method's documentation contains an example with the code you need to write.

Instead of writing the login and registration code yourself you can also use the built-in [login controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) like the [CreateUserWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.aspx) control to add a new wizard, the [ChangePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.changepassword.aspx) control to change a password etc.

Comment: I have changed my database already, I change unique identifier to int datatype. and I can not use this.